# Presheaf Clarification

Tags: category-theory

so I am reading through the Wikipedia article on sheaves, specifically the part on expressing the notion of a presheaf in terms of category theory. The article states that to define a presheaf on a topological space X you first define the category of open sets on X to be category O(X) whose objects are the open sets of X and whose morphisms are inclusions.
Question: My understanding of morphisms are that they are an abstract notion of functions between objects so how exactly are inclusions morphisms. - thanks

Comment: Do you know what a morphism is?

Comment: Morphisms in a category are an *abstraction* from the idea of functions or homomorphisms, but that doesn't mean that all of them are actually functions. Much like many ideas in topology are abstractions from properties of $\mathbb{R}$, but there are all kinds of topologies that don't look a bit like the reals.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just being morphisms. You *define* the category $\mathbf{Op}(X)$ declaring:

- Objects: open sets $U \subset X$ of $X$.
- Morphisms: inclusions of open sets, $i: V \hookrightarrow U$.
- Composition of morphisms: composition of inclusions, as plain maps. If $j: W \hookrightarrow V$ and $i: V \hookrightarrow U $ are inclusions of open sets, their composition $i\circ j: W \hookrightarrow U$ is also an iclusion of open sets.
- Identity morphism: indeed, $\mathrm{id}_U : U \hookrightarrow U$ is a honest inclusion.

You verify the axioms of a category, and that's it: where is the problem?

**EDIT.** Nevertheless, as a first introduction to (pre) sheaves, I would think first about a particular example of a (pre) sheaf. For instance the (pre) sheaf of continuous functions of the real line, $U \mapsto {\cal F}(U) ={\cal C}^0(U, \mathbb{R})$, where $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open set (with the usual topology of the real line, for example).

So, in this example, for every open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, you have an abelian group $ {\cal F}(U) $ and, for every inclusion of open sets $i: V \hookrightarrow U$, a morphism of groups $\rho_{UV}: {\cal F}(U) \longrightarrow {\cal F}(V)$ -namely, you just restrict every continuous function $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to $V$, precomposing with the inclusion: $\rho_{UV}(f) = f_{| V} = f\circ i : V \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

You can easily verify the axioms for a (pre) sheaf.

But, instead of going too categorically too soon, I would start with a more elementary definition, like the one you can find in [Hartshorne's book](http://books.google.es/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), which has served right lots of mathematicians without ever needing to think of a presheaf as a functor ${\cal F} : \mathbf{Op}(X)^{op} \longrightarrow {\cal A}$, and bothering yourself about the category $\mathbf{Op}(X)$, its *opposite* category (yes!), functors and the like. Don't get me wrong: I love all this categorical stuff, but I don't think it's the best way to start learning about sheaves.